# Is it possible to apply GradCam to a TF Lite model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have been studying about GradCam and I noticed most cases are used on a Keras/Tensorflow model. However I have a tensorflow lite model that has been compiled to .tflite format. I am not sure if it's even possible to access my CNN layers after it's been compiled, given that I tried using keras library to load the model and it only accepts specific file types, not exactly .tflite since it threw errors:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("/content/drive/My Drive/tensorflow_lite_model.tflite")
```

It gives the error:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist
```

What I was trying to do was to print the .tflite models using model.summary as a way to confirm If I could perform any operation with the model layers. If that is so, then I don't think it's possible to use Grad-Cam with a tensorflow lite model.

Therefore, I would like to know If that is true, or did I just try to validate it, the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

TFLite model file is a different serialization format with the TensorFlow model formats, keras and saved model.

Since you already have a TFLite model, you need to use the TensorFlow Lite Interpreter API, instead of using the TensorFlow API.

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python) for the details.

The TF GradCam model can be converted into the TFLite model. It is technically possible to convert any TF models to the corresponding TFLite model. If you have any issues with the conversion, please file bug at the tensorflow github.